# JBoss EAP 7 GA の「GA」とは何？

Tags: java

[このページ](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/version-7.0.beta/700-beta-release-notes/)に書かれている`JBoss EAP 7 GA`の`GA`とは何を意味しているのでしょうか？
単に`JBoss EAP 7`と書いた場合と、何が違いますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

直前の「EAP 7 Beta release」と比較しているので、「JBoss EAP 7 GA release」は「JBoss EAP 7のGA（General availability）リリース」という意味ではないでしょうか。

参考：[Software release life cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle)